# Ubuntu freeze and don't come back without reboot

Tags: freeze, 23.04

I set up fresh Ubuntu 23.04 (with awesome-wm) on my PC and am now experiencing some freezes.
Several times I left computer unattended, and when I return I see this situation:

- The LED on my monitor goes to wait-mode (the same like when pc is turn off), nothing on the screen.
- Any keyboard press and mouse movement do nothing. System doesn't wake up.
- The fans and LED on PC looks like pc is working just fine.
- I wrote a cron which write current date to a file every minute, and it stops.
- System doesn't respond to Magic SysRq key commands and power button.

I can't find anything in the syslog. It looks like computer just  stops responding.
I tried to replicate the situation by using pm-suspend, but after halt command everything looks different: LED and fans stops, any interaction successful wakes up computer.

What could it be?
What should I investigate to gather more data?
Maybe some experiments would be useful?

syslog:

```
2023-10-16T01:46:01.282352+03:00 doc-pc2 CRON[8809]: (doc) CMD (echo `date` >> ~/test.log)
2023-10-16T01:47:01.302912+03:00 doc-pc2 CRON[8817]: (doc) CMD (echo `date` >> ~/test.log)
2023-10-16T01:47:12.066460+03:00 doc-pc2 openconnect[5484]: DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
2023-10-16T01:48:01.314483+03:00 doc-pc2 CRON[8824]: (doc) CMD (echo `date` >> ~/test.log)
2023-10-16T01:48:25.019814+03:00 doc-pc2 openconnect[5484]: DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
2023-10-16T01:49:01.330367+03:00 doc-pc2 CRON[8831]: (doc) CMD (echo `date` >> ~/test.log)
2023-10-16T01:49:37.796553+03:00 doc-pc2 openconnect[5484]: DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
2023-10-16T01:50:01.346756+03:00 doc-pc2 CRON[8838]: (doc) CMD (echo `date` >> ~/test.log)
2023-10-16T01:50:49.046793+03:00 doc-pc2 openconnect[5484]: DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
2023-10-16T01:51:01.363303+03:00 doc-pc2 CRON[8849]: (doc) CMD (echo `date` >> ~/test.log)
2023-10-16T01:52:01.117543+03:00 doc-pc2 openconnect[5484]: DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
2023-10-16T01:52:01.380847+03:00 doc-pc2 CRON[8877]: (doc) CMD (echo `date` >> ~/test.log)
2023-10-16T01:53:01.395936+03:00 doc-pc2 CRON[8911]: (doc) CMD (echo `date` >> ~/test.log) 
2023-10-16T02:01:24.273812+03:00 doc-pc2 systemd-modules-load[385]: Inserted module 'lp'  <-- ACTUAL REBOOT
2023-10-16T02:01:24.273947+03:00 doc-pc2 systemd-modules-load[385]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
2023-10-16T02:01:24.274021+03:00 doc-pc2 systemd-modules-load[385]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
2023-10-16T02:01:24.274030+03:00 doc-pc2 systemd-modules-load[385]: Inserted module 'msr'
2023-10-16T02:01:24.274036+03:00 doc-pc2 lvm[372]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "hdd5" monitored
2023-10-16T02:01:24.274041+03:00 doc-pc2 lvm[372]:   1 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" monitored
2023-10-16T02:01:24.274048+03:00 doc-pc2 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-journal-flush.service - Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
```

test.log from cron (`` * * * * * echo `date` >> ~/test.log ``)

```
Mon Oct 16 01:51:01 AM MSK 2023
Mon Oct 16 01:52:01 AM MSK 2023
Mon Oct 16 01:53:01 AM MSK 2023 <-- LAST LOG BEFORE FREEZE
Mon Oct 16 02:02:00 AM MSK 2023 <-- POWER BUTTON REBOOT
Mon Oct 16 02:03:01 AM MSK 2023
Mon Oct 16 02:04:01 AM MSK 2023
Mon Oct 16 02:05:01 AM MSK 2023
Mon Oct 16 02:06:01 AM MSK 2023
Mon Oct 16 02:07:01 AM MSK 2023
Mon Oct 16 02:08:01 AM MSK 2023
```

Comment: Look at the logs leading to the previous reboot with `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`. If nothing shows up there, suspect power/overheating/ventilation.